# Setting error code 500 for exchange HttpServerExchange after migration .wars from JBOSS 7.1 TO JBOSS 7.2

Tags: jboss

We are migrating existing .war files from Jboss 7.1 EAP to Jboss 7.2 eap. Deployment getting completed successfully on 7.2 but when the user tries to access the webpage, it's downloading instead.

==============================================================================================
20:48:10,999 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.error-response] (default task-1) Setting error code 500 for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /pfgcEdmCustomUIWebApp/useropco.html request {Connection=[keep-alive], Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.9], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[njinfmdmt02.performance.pfgc.com:18080]} response {}}: java.lang.RuntimeException
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.setStatusCode(HttpServerExchange.java:1410) [undertow-core-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:317) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104) [undertow-servlet-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360) [undertow-core-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001]
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1349)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_222]

20:48:14,283 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl] (Thread-7 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@67650b6d)) Scanning for expires on jms.queue.DLQ
20:48:14,283 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl] (Thread-7 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@67650b6d)) Scanning for expires on jms.queue.DLQ done
20:48:44,284 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@67650b6d)) Scanning for expires on jms.queue.DLQ
20:48:44,284 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@67650b6d)) Scanning for expires on jms.queue.DLQ done
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) PeriodicRecovery: background thread Status <== SCANNING
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) PeriodicRecovery: background thread scanning
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) Periodic recovery first pass at Mon, 2 Nov 2020 20:48:51
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) processing /StateManager/BasicAction/TwoPhaseCoordinator/AtomicAction transactions
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery)
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) AtomicActionRecoveryModule first pass
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) processing /StateManager/BasicAction/TwoPhaseCoordinator/AtomicAction transactions
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery)
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.txoj] (Periodic Recovery) TORecoveryModule - first pass
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery)
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery)
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) XARecoveryModule state change IDLE->FIRST_PASS

20:48:51,826 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) Local XARecoveryModule - first pass
20:48:51,826 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl] (Periodic Recovery) Recovery user name=mdmadm
20:48:51,831 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl] (Periodic Recovery) Recovery Subject=Subject:
Principal: mdmadm
Private Credential: javax.resource.spi.security.PasswordCredential@81cfdca

20:48:51,831 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl] (Periodic Recovery) Open managed connection (Subject:
Principal: mdmadm
Private Credential: javax.resource.spi.security.PasswordCredential@81cfdca
)